# Highcharts 3.0 'invisible' columns

Tags: highcharts

I've just upgraded to latest version and the column chart (which is dynamically updated) works on IE9 (?!?) but does not on latest Chrome
[image: IE screenshot]

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Comment: I am experiencing this too, but when I try to paste my options into a jsfiddle, the problem doesn't occur. I also tried stripping all other javascript out my page and it still occurs. It has to do with the animation on the column charts as the scaleY on the series SVGElement isn't getting eased from .001 to 1. I tried tracing it through the Highcharts and JQuery but had no luck finding the problem. Setting the animation to false for the column chart will allow it to render in my case, but if you want the animation, then you are out of luck. Occurs in Chrome/Firefox. HC 3.0/JQuery 1.7.1

Comment: I was able to recreate the issue in a jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/zAFmS/1/

Comment: I suggest to use chart object and addSeries in callback Highcharts initialization like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/zAFmS/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a highcharts bug that has been fixed. I tested their latest work (http://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.js)  before reporting the bug, and the problem went away for me.

I believe this is the github issue: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1623

Comment: Yep, I've just downloaded this js file and it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared example which add columns dynamically (via button)

http://jsfiddle.net/DQTMP/

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

        }]
    },function(chart){

        $('#btn').click(function(){
            chart.addSeries({
                type:'column',
                data:[1,2,3,4,5]
            });
        });

    });
```

Please let me know if you come across problem with this example in your Chrome.